# Transform excel table looping through columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

I'm working on a Excel table transformation into another file for database upload. The tables usually looks like this:
[image]

The result should be a long list looking like this:

[image]

And this is the code I was trying to use...any thoughts?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np


df_excel = pd.read_excel('Excel_Forecast.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

df_details = df_excel['Details']

df_base = []

for column in df_excel.columns[2:]:
    df_base['Details'].append(df_excel['Details'])
    df_base = DataFrame(df_base.append(df_excel[(column)]),columns=['Amount'])

df_base.to_excel('Temp.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.melt`:

```
df.melt(['Group', 'Item'])
```

Comment: Elegant, simple and working beautifully! Really apreciate! ;-)